# Session drops about every 30 minutes

Tags: php, session, ubuntu, digital-ocean

Am I doing something wrong? I am running the following on every page load, and about every 30 minutes if nothing happens, my session is gone. I can close the browser and open it back up and the session is still there, but after about 30 minutes it's gone. What is causing this?

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 10);
session_set_cookie_params(365 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 10, "/");

session_start();
```

When I look in chrome to see when the session expires, it says:

```
Tuesday, January 14, 2025 at 10:26:13 PM
```

What is causing me to lose my session?

Comment: I am just curious, how do you track session data with chrome? Some plugin or you are doing some output with php ?

Comment: `Settings -> Show advanced settings... -> Content Settings -> All cookies and site data... -> mywebsite.com -> PHPSESSID`

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about this. Thanks.

Comment: About your question, maybe this could be helpful http://blog.centresource.com/2006/05/23/php-session-lifetime-an-adventure/ as well as this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9915572/3402095

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are stored in the /tmp dir until the browser is closed. In your case you should store session data in a database to look at it later if that's what you're trying to accomplish.

Sessions are designed such that they are "Session" based. In other words, if you close your Browser (which is essentially your session), it is suppose to go away.

Put the session id and the session data in a table. Look up the session id from the cookie PHPSESSID and look up the session data from your database.

What information are you storing? if its user and pass you shouldn't store the in cookies, its easy to access that information if there was a hacker trying to access that information.